# Display daily consumption grafana using prometheus datasource

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql, victoriametrics, metricsql

I’m using grafana v9.5.1 and my datasource is prometheus.
I'm really new to monitoring.
I have a metric called container_network_transmit_bytes_total.
I want to create a graph which the X-axis represents the date of the day and the Y-axis represents the total consumption for that specific day.

I want to manage it using some kind of PromQL or MetricsQL.
Here’s a picture of what I’m trying to achieve.

[image]

I tried using increase but I can't get into something like above. Is it possible to get something like a list of values and timestamps for each day in the last N days?

Answer (score 2):

It is defensively possible.

1. Add **Bar chart** panel.
2. Use query `increase(container_network_transmit_bytes_total[$__interval])`
3. Set *Min interval* to `1d` (Query options on top of the query, near data source selection)

You will get something like this:
[image]